# Angular2 - Custom Pipe for *ngFor to filter results by JSON Value

Tags: json, angular, typescript, angularjs-filter

Today I'm trying to learn about custom pipes.  I can get everything to work fine until I reach the part where I create the args for the PipeTransform.  No matter what I read online, I can't seem to pick up where I'm off.

[View Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/YQ2dVyteOBfYDODSFGyA?p=preview)

**I was hoping to have a filter I could re-use for each card type, Visa, MC, AMEX, etc.  and call it from a variable in the pipe.**

```
*ngFor="let transaction of ('./app/api/transactions.json' | fetch | cardType:['Visa'])"
```

My problem is here, in the cardtype.pipe.ts file:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'cardType' })

export class CardTypePipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: string, args: string[]): any {

        // I can't figure out the args here...

    }
}
```

Here is sample data that shows 2 Visa transactions and 1 MC.  My goal is to only show VISA card types in a table.  I'm calling a JSON file for the data:

```
[
      {
        "cardType": "Visa",
        "amount": 153.42
      },
      {
        "cardType": "MasterCard",
        "amount": 296.11
      },
      {
        "cardType": "Visa",
        "amount": 74.57
      }
]
```

My Table:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Card Type</th>
            <th class="text-xs-right">Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let transaction of ('./app/api/transactions.json' | fetch | cardType:['Visa'])">
            <td>{{ transaction.cardType }}</td>
            <td class="text-xs-right">{{ transaction.amount | currency:'USD':true }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are putting to much logic in the template.
It's far more superior and easy to test if you put that logic in the controller where it belongs.

```
interface Transaction {
  cardType: 'Visa' | 'MasterCard';
  amount: number;
}

@Component({
  // you know the stuff...
})
class TransactionView {

  transactions: Observable<Transaction[]>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('./app/api/transactions.json')
      .map(r => r.json())
      .filter(transaction => transaction.cardType === 'Visa')
      .subscribe(transactions => this.transactions = transactions);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Leon.  since I am learning, I was looking to understand how to do the solution specifically through the use of custom pipes.  I feel i'm close but missing that last piece.  I think your .filter may lead me somewhere.